# Minimum value of an array

Tags: java

I would like to write a program that reads an array of integers and finds the minimum value.
The first line contains the size of an array.

Output

An integer number representing the minimum in the input array.
Input:
5
5 1 4 2 3

My code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        int[] c = new int[a ];
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {

            c[i] = sc.nextInt();


        }

        Arrays.sort(c);
         int b= c[0] > 0 ? c[0]: c[c.length -1];
        for (int i =1; i < c.length - 1; i++){
            if(c[i] < 0){
              if(c[i] > b){
                  b = c[i];
              }
            }
            else{


               if (c[i] < b){
                   b= c[i];
               }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

My output:
3
-1 -2 -3

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you are sorting the array, then the first element would be the minimum. Why the code to find it?

Comment: Alternatively, `Arrays.stream(c).min().getAsInt();`

Comment: "My output: 3 -1 -2 -3" => That can't be! The only output is `System.out.println(b)` and `b` is an `int`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, not reproducible

Comment: Arrays.stream is overkill for a trivial task like this.

Comment: Why downwote a beginners first confused attempt to solve a problem? Help by clearing the confusion is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it more complicated than necessary. No need to sort the array. Just set a variable to be equal to the first value in the array. Then scan through the array setting the variable to the actual array element if it is less than the present variable value.

Comment: You're absolutely correct!  "Find minimum element" can easily be accomplished with one loop and 4-5 lines of code ;)

Comment: Yes, and in my world "writing code to find minimum" does not mean "sort it"